# How to add list to end of each line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a list where each line have different length:

```
123
1234
12345
123456
```

and there is a list of words:

```
11
22
33
44
```

How to merge these two lists to get:

```
12311
123422
1234533
12345644
```

Answer (score 1):

It is my frequent use case.
You can try following.

1. Select column data that you want to paste using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>
2. Copy using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
3. Move your cursor to the right of the first word and then paste it. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

why not just copy those two lists side by side into columns in Excel/open Office?
then copy both rows back to Notepad++ and remove spaces/tabs?
from your description of the Problem this should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in multiple step process:

1. open both file
2. select the names from second file with column mode edition

   - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>
   - With the mouse, select the block that contains all the words to copy
   - Copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Go to first file

   - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>
   - With the mouse, select a block ahead the column
   - Paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
4. Remove extra spaces

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
   - Find what: `\h+`
   - Replace with:   #a single space
   - CHECK *Wrap around*
   - CHECK *Regular expression*
   - <kbd>Replace all</kbd>